# I am a new learner in python and I can't understand how these codes containing functions work

Tags: python, function, variables

```py
def createmultipier(x):
    return lambda y: y*x
multiply= createmultipier(10)
print(multiply(15))
```

Here `multiply` is a variable then how did he put value to it and how did that work?

Comment: Next time write a title relative to **your** exact problem, not a generic one like "please help", "fix that" that anybody could have, it help having people come to see it

Comment: Read about [lambdas](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) in the documentation. StackOverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`createmultiplier(10)` creates a function that multiplies its argument by 10.  That's what `multiply` is assigned to -- hence `multiply(15)` returns `150`.

To put it another way:

```
multiply = createmultiplier(10)
```

has the same effect as doing:

```
def multiply(y)
    return 10 * y
```

The point of a function like `createmultiplier` is to let you create functions without a `def` statement *and* without having to hard-code implementation details like the constant `10`.  For example, if you wanted multipliers for all numbers from 1 to 4, you could do:

```
def times_1(y):
    return 1 * y

def times_2(y):
    return 2 * y

def times_3(y):
    return 3 * y

def times_4(y):
    return 4 * y

multipliers = [times_1, times_2, times_3, times_4]
print([m(10) for m in multipliers])  # [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

but it's much easier to do:

```
def create_multiplier(x):
    return lambda y: y*x

multipliers = [create_multiplier(x) for x in range(1, 5)]
print([m(10) for m in multipliers])  # [10, 20, 30, 40]
```